# Font and config problem with MikTex on Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: miktex

I'm trying to compile a .tex file, but I get the error message

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecrm1200): Font ecrm1200 at 600 not found"
```

Other answers suggest that I should add a suitable line into the config file by running

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

But this command gives me the error message

```
Environment variable EDITOR is not defined.
```

But in my opinion, I have it set:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/xed
```

Especially, the .cfg file cautions that these should not be edited manually. Is this "EDITOR not defined" a bug or am I missing something?

On Windows `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` opens Notepad and a suitable .cfg file, but on my Linux Mint it doesn't work.

Comment: installation was perfomed as described here: https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx?

Comment: normally there should be no need to add the map-file, miktex does it. Try to run simply `updmap` to update your map files. The editor error sound like a bug, so report it in the github tracker.

Comment: Yes, installed using apt. Finished with "miktexsetup finish". Trying to run "updmap" suggests that I should apt install texlive-base?

Edit. Now I'm guessing what went wrong. I uninstalled Tex Live before installink Miktex, and updmap-binaries got deleted

Comment: is there any particular reason to use miktex on linux? The overwhelming majority of linux users will be using texlive and the overwhelming majority of miktex users are on windows, so the number of people who can offer first hand help with any issues is strictly limited.

Comment: no miktex should have its own updmap binaries (or perhaps try `initexmf --mkmaps` but as David wrote: most linux users use texlive, so why are you trying to switch to miktex?

Comment: I got some error message when trying to install Texlive packages. Miktex worked on my Windows computer without any problems, so I assumed it would be "easier".

Thanks for the advice, I will try to erase all Miktex and reinstall Texlive on Linux.